# Не могу найти ошибку в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, криптография

пишу такой мини-проектик. Идея проекта заключается в шифровании файлов. В ходе написания кода сталкивался с многими ошибками и успешно фиксил их. Но данную ошибку разрешить не в силах, даже понятия не имею в чем она заключается. Поэтому прошу у вас помощи. Ошибка возникает в файле ***crypt.py***, нужно выполнить код чтобы файлы ***crypt.py***(код отвечающий за шифрование) и *key.py* создалис. **Сама ошибка возникает когда выполняется файл crypt.py**
 
 
Возникла новая ошибка, **при выполнении файла key.py зашифрованные файлы не расшифровывается** 
**Лучше каких либо слов, вот код:**

```py
direct = input("Write the root directory: ")
password = input("Write the password: ")

with open("crypt.py", "w") as crypt:
    crypt.write('''
import os, sys
def crypt(file):
    import pyAesCrypt
    password = "''' + str(password) +'''"
    bufferSize = 512 * 1024
    pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(str(file), str(file)+".crp", password, buffferSize)
    print("[crypted] '" + str(file) + ".crp'")
    os.remove(file)
def walk(dir):
    for name in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, name)
        if os.path.isfile(path): crypt(path)
        else: walk(path)
walk("''' + str(direct) +'''")

os.remove(str(sys.argv[0]))
                ''')
    print("[+] File 'crypt.py' successfully saved!")
with open("key.py", "w") as key:
    key.write('''
import os
def decrypt(file):
    import pyAesCrypt
    # line
    password = "''' + str(password) + '''"
    bufferSize = 512 * 1024
    pyAesCrypt.decryptFile(str(file), str(os.path.splittext(file)[0]), password, bufferSize)
    print("[decrypted '" + str(os.path.splittext(file)[0]) + "'")
    os.remove(file)
def walk(dir):
    for name in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, name)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            try: decrypt(path)
            except: pass
        else: walk(path)
walk("''' + str(direct) + '''")
        ''')
    print("[+] File 'key.py' successfully saved!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня запустилось, установил pyAesCrypt, и изменил buffferSize на bufferSize. Выполнилось без ошибок.
Чтобы файлы успешно декодировать, нужно изменить код файла key.py на что то подобное

```
def decrypt(file):
    import pyAesCrypt
    # line
    password = "123"
    bufferSize = 512 * 1024
    file = str(file)
    split = file.split("\\")
    split = os.path.split(file)[1][:-4]
    pyAesCrypt.decryptFile(file, split, password, bufferSize)
    print("[decrypted '" + str(os.path.split(file)[0]) + "'")
    os.remove(file)
```

Comment: вы выполнили файл crypt.py?

Comment: да, при этом все файлы лежащие в этой директории зашифровались, покажите какая ошибка у вас возникает